# json-server not returning a single item in React.js

Tags: reactjs, json-server

I¡m having problems with json Server.

**After installing it and starting up the server it returns the data correctly but if I want to ask for a single user, for example, it returns nothing.
With Thunder Client it didn't even work. With postman it does.

I've installed: **npm i -D json-server**
I've added an script:** "server": "json-server ./users.json -p 4000"**

Server in port: **http://localhost:4000/users/**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6coPy.png)

But If I ask for just 1 user: **http://localhost:4000/users/1**

All it does is return an empty array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwLo1.png)

Console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBkRs.png)

Comment: There is no user with id `1` ... use for instance `c3ce080a...` instead ... If you want to get at most `xx` users, use a `?_limit=xx` query ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding `/1` gives you the single user with `id: 1` if it exists. Since all your users seem to have longer uuid's, you get an empty result.

To get an array with at most one user, you can request `http://localhost:4000/users?_limit=1`.